# Optimise EF query to generate all points for graph in 1 call

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have some C# to extract data from a db to populate a line graph. The x axis being date and there being a few different values on the y axis for each date.

The values for the y Axis is a count() of "Property" entities that are either Compliant, Warning or Error for the given date on the x Axis. Figuring out if the property is Compliant, Warning or Error is done in the ComplianceManager.PropertyIsCompliant/Warning/Error(DateTime) expressions.

At the moment the EF code has to do a call to the DB for each value, for each date. I've tried to write it to defer loading until a final Count() for each point on the y axis. However it still has to run a query for each.

I've tried Include()ing the various other relationships from the main referenced table (Property) but it doesn't alter the execution at all.

```
        /* trimmed... DatesToLoad is a List<DateTime> of the points for the x axis */

        ComplianceOverviewPeriod result = new ComplianceOverviewPeriod();

        var allProperties = propertyRepo.GetProperties(); //IQueryable<Property>


        var points = (from d in DatesToLoad
                      select new
                      {
                          compliantCount = allProperties.Count(complianceManager.PropertyIsCompliant(d)),
                          warningCount = allProperties.Count(complianceManager.PropertyHasWarnings(d)),
                          errorCount = allProperties.Count(complianceManager.PropertyHasErrors(d)),
                          unknownCount = allProperties.Count(complianceManager.PropertyComplianceKnown(d)),
                          readingDate = d
                      });


        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            var complianceReading = new ComplianceOverview();

            complianceReading.CompliantProperties = point.compliantCount;
            complianceReading.ErrorProperties = point.errorCount;
            complianceReading.WarningProperties = point.warningCount;
            complianceReading.UntestedProperties = point.unknownCount;
            result.CompliancePoints.Add(complianceReading);
        }
```

Is there something I'm missing that will make EF defer loading for ALL dates and ALL y-values until the very end and then load the lot at once?

Comment: Instead of `select new {...}` try putting the results directly into  a ComplianceOverview object with `select new ComplianceOverview {...}`

Comment: Changing the creation of the overview object didn't improve the performance. It still utilised the same number of queries to create the graph.

Comment: You don't need to do the `foreach` loop any more though.

Comment: Yes, If I remove the foreach and create the objects in the select it still uses the same number of queries